# Is it possible, with RLink, for Mathematica to perform operations on an R data.frame?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, rlink

In my humble opinion, Mathematica produces the best and unique-looking graphics for data analysis in general. However, exclusively using it for data analysis can be troublesome as it doesn't have the niceties of dedicated programs for formating/modifying/filtering data, such as R.

RLink seems to be a promising package: use the data sets located in R and send it to Mathematica for, let's say, visual analysis. But in every RLink tutorial I looked into, there is no clear explanation as to how to establish this kind of communication between the two softwares.

For example, I would like, in Mathematica, to be able to use this kind of command: "from R, use `data$Var1` and apply the `ListPlot[]` function to it.

So, in a few words: does anyone know of an exhaustive manual/guide for RLink, or something that would teach me how to do this kind of operation?

Comment: `Plot` is for plotting functions, `ListPlot` is for plotting data. The RLink user guide in the documentation is pretty exhaustive, it seems to me.

Comment: Could you tell me how to tell RLink to refer itself to a data.frame already present in an R environment?

Comment: This information is directly in the [*RLink User Guide*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/tutorial/UsingRLink.html). Scroll down to the *Executing R Code and Getting Data from R* section where it actually uses an R `data.frame` in an example. This returns an `RDataFrame` that is an instance of an [`RObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/ref/RObject.html).  `RObject` also has an R `dataframe` example in its documentation. The documentation is your friend.

Comment: Also, [`FromRForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/ref/FromRForm.html).

Comment: I had already read this section of the documentation: in the example given there, the `data.frame` used was created from Mathematica. What if I already have a `data.frame` set up in an R environment? How do you tell RLink to look in that specific environment? Maybe I'm missing something here, but I don't see where the documentation helps for that specific problem?

Comment: Are you referring to an R distribution or an R session?  If an R distribution see the `"RHomeLocation"` option of [`InstallR`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/ref/InstallR.html). If an R session then how would you connect to the R session from another R session?  Then [`REvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/ref/REvaluate.html) that code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was referring to an R session. However, I do not know how to connect two R sessions together. Would you also know how to do that?

Comment: We are going out of context of this forum but there are [a few options](http://bfy.tw/9Hhz).